# HTML Overlapping text

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-float

I am writing something similar to a crossword puzzle in HTML. There is a 9x9 table and in each cell, we need two things:

- A number in the top left corner of the cell (small text, right up against the margin)
- A letter right in the middle of the cell (big text)

Is this possible without using background images? We have tried floating divs inside the cells, but this is not working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You can put a div with predefined width and height inside each cell, make the div position:relative; and then put your other elements as position:absolute inside the div...

something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/battal84/Nt5uB/
?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at CSS counters 
Something like

```css
.counter-parent-element { 
  counter-reset: your-counter-variable; 
}
.counter-element { 
  position: relative; 
  padding: 1em; 
  font-size: 18px; 
  border: 1px solid 
}
.counter-element:before {
  counter-increment: your-counter-variable; 
  content: counter(your-counter-variable); 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 2px; 
  left:2px; 
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table class="counter-parent-element">
<tr>
<td class="counter-element">a</td>
<td class="counter-element">b</td>
<td class="counter-element">c</td>
<td class="counter-element">d</td>
<td class="counter-element">e</td>
<td class="counter-element">f</td>
<td class="counter-element">g</td>
<td class="counter-element">h</td>
<td class="counter-element">i</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="counter-element">j</td>
<td class="counter-element">k</td>
<td class="counter-element">l</td>
<td class="counter-element">m</td>
<td class="counter-element">n</td>
<td class="counter-element">o</td>
<td class="counter-element">p</td>
<td class="counter-element">q</td>
<td class="counter-element">r</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="counter-element">s</td>
<td class="counter-element">t</td>
<td class="counter-element">u</td>
<td class="counter-element">v</td>
<td class="counter-element">w</td>
<td class="counter-element">x</td>
<td class="counter-element">y</td>
<td class="counter-element">z</td>
<td class="counter-element">a</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="counter-element">b</td>
<td class="counter-element">c</td>
<td class="counter-element">d</td>
<td class="counter-element">e</td>
<td class="counter-element">f</td>
<td class="counter-element">g</td>
<td class="counter-element">h</td>
<td class="counter-element">i</td>
<td class="counter-element">j</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="counter-element">k</td>
<td class="counter-element">l</td>
<td class="counter-element">m</td>
<td class="counter-element">n</td>
<td class="counter-element">o</td>
<td class="counter-element">p</td>
<td class="counter-element">q</td>
<td class="counter-element">r</td>
<td class="counter-element">s</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="counter-element">t</td>
<td class="counter-element">u</td>
<td class="counter-element">v</td>
<td class="counter-element">w</td>
<td class="counter-element">x</td>
<td class="counter-element">y</td>
<td class="counter-element">z</td>
<td class="counter-element">a</td>
<td class="counter-element">b</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="counter-element">c</td>
<td class="counter-element">d</td>
<td class="counter-element">e</td>
<td class="counter-element">f</td>
<td class="counter-element">g</td>
<td class="counter-element">h</td>
<td class="counter-element">i</td>
<td class="counter-element">j</td>
<td class="counter-element">k</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="counter-element">l</td>
<td class="counter-element">m</td>
<td class="counter-element">n</td>
<td class="counter-element">o</td>
<td class="counter-element">p</td>
<td class="counter-element">q</td>
<td class="counter-element">r</td>
<td class="counter-element">s</td>
<td class="counter-element">t</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="counter-element">u</td>
<td class="counter-element">v</td>
<td class="counter-element">w</td>
<td class="counter-element">x</td>
<td class="counter-element">y</td>
<td class="counter-element">z</td>
<td class="counter-element">a</td>
<td class="counter-element">b</td>
<td class="counter-element">c</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @William this looks excellent.  Is this what you needed 8 years ago?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        height:100px;
        width:300px;
    }
    table td {
        border:1px solid #000;
        font-size:20px;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:33%;
    }
    table td > div {
        font-size:10px;
        position:absolute; 
        top:5px; 
        left:5px;
    }
    </style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="a">First</div>A</td>
        <td><div class="b">Second</div>B</td>
        <td><div class="c">Third</div>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It's a sample with 3 columns, but you can replicate to as many as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you apply the float to the text itself and turn it into a block element?

eg css

```
    .smallnumber {font-size:0.5em; 
                  margin:-0.25em .25em .25em .25em; 
                  display:block; 
                  float:right;}

    .normaltext {font-size:1em; 
                 margin:0.5em; 
                 display:block; 
                 float:left;}
```

html

```
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td><span class="normtext">1</span><span class="smallnum">2</span></td>
    <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>11</td>
    </tr>
```